# Cannot resolve symbol which is a type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

```
Type myType = Type.GetType(nameOfTypeString);
DoSomething(typeof(myType));

// signature of DoSomething
DoSomething(Type myType)
```

Complains it cannot resolve myType.

Comment: Also why there is generics tag selected ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `typeof` operator returns an instance of the `Type` class.

In this case, you already have an instance of `Type`. You should be able to simply pass it to the method:

```
DoSomething(myType);
```